# `Socket error: Operation not permitted` with Linux socket

Tags: macos, sockets, ping, ipv4, icmp

I am trying to write an ICMP ping program in C++ but I am getting following error with `socket()`:

`Socket error: Operation not permitted`

The code snippet is:

```
sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP );
if ( sockfd == -1 )
{
  cerr << '\n' << "\nSocket error: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I am running this on MacOS Mojave. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Opening a raw socket requires privilege.  Ordinary users cannot do it.  This may be of interest to you: [How does macOS allow Standard users to ping?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312857/how-does-macos-allow-standard-users-to-ping)

Comment: Note also: it's not a *Linux* socket on macOS.  It would be most conventional to just say "socket", but if you need to distinguish it from some other kind of socket then "network socket" or maybe "POSIX socket" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on Debian. From https://superuser.com/questions/288521/problem-with-ping-open-socket-operation-not-permitted

```
    sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ep $(which ping)
```